# Query Parent Accounts with its child accounts

Tags: apex

How to find Accounts with no child Accounts? I tried Aggregate Query but its not returning proper result and inner query isn't supported for Self-Relation. Thoughts?

Comment: If you thought in terms of rolling up the count of child accounts to parent accounts, their roll-up values would be zero. That might be one way of approaching it. You'd want to also make certain that account didn't have a parent account as part of your criteria.

Answer (score 6):

You need to do two queries. One with AggregateResult to get the account id's which are parent of other account. Then do a query excluding those account ids.

```
Set<Id> parentId = new Set<Id>();
for(AggregateResult a : [select parentid p from account group by parentid])
{
    if(a.get('p') != NULL)
    {
        parentId.add((Id)a.get('p'));
    }        
}
List<Account> acc = [select id from account where id not in : parentid];
```

**Edit:**

Per @sfdcfox suggestion, the above code can be optimized as

```
Set<Id> parentId = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([SELECT ParentId Id FROM Account WHERE ParentId != NULL GROUP BY ParentId]).keySet();
List<Account> acc = [select id from account where id not in : parentid];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Minor optimization: `Set<Id> parentIds = new Map<Id, AggregrateResult>([SELECT ParentId Id FROM Account WHERE ParentId != NULL GROUP BY ParentId]).keySet();`

Comment: @sfdcfox Care for an explanation as how the map assigned with aggregate query have keyset of id of account rather than id of aggregateresult?

Comment: This is only a comment, so you might be interested in asking that question (I don't believe it's a duplicate), but the short answer is that when you alias 'Id' to a field, the `Map<Id, SObject>(sobjectList)` constructor is smart enough to use the aliased field as the key, so since we grouped by ParentId and aliased it to Id, we get a map where the key is the ParentId, and the value is the AggregateResult (say, if we were summing/avg/min/max etc...). Also, AggregateResult doesn't have an Id field naturally, since it's a special type of SObject.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the work

```
select Account.Name from Contact where AccountId not in (select ParentId from Account) group by Account.Name
```

I am querying all `Account` names from the `Contact` object where the account has not children and I group that by `Name` to not get duplicates (cause an Account can have multiple Contacts)

If you need to get the `AccountId`, just replace all `Account.Name` with `AccountId`

*My query is based on the Contact object because I cannot query on Account and use a subquery based on account I am getting this error*

> The inner and outer selects should not be on the same object type